# Responsive CSS for phones/small screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to setup a basic responsive wordpress theme. To start, I grabbed the toolbox theme from wordpress.org and added [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) responsive css/js.

I added some basic test styles, just to reduce the padding on smaller screens and change the color to indicate that its working. For some reason, the styles for landscape phones are not working.

You can view my site [here](http://mrglass.org).

My responsive CSS code:

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
    body    {
        padding-left: 50px;
        padding-right: 50px;
        color: green;
    }
}

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px) { 
    body    {
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-right: 30px;
        color: purple;
    }
}

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
    body    {
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        color: blue;
    }
}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { 
    body    {
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not only landscape phone, it is also not working on Small tablet landscape (800x600), Tablet portrait (768x1024), Tablet landscape (1024x768)

Comment: @refhat well, this was just a start (the sizes are actually fromt he responsive bootstrap guide). I dont have rules for the sizes you mentioned, but I do have a rule that should cover phones (<481px wide) and I can't figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: the rules I mentioned, you need not bother about them just make sure these spans add to 12 as per twitter bootstrap. As far as your rule that doesn't cover/works the/on iphones(481px). It means you havent set the mediaquery breakpoint properly.

Comment: @refhat Yes, the layout will add up to 12 (i think it does now). Also, I am testing simply by changing the size of my desktop browser window. As I drag the width smaller, it cycles through the first 3 colors but not the last. Also checked on my android phone to be sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you haven't set the meta tag for viewport properly:

It should be like below:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; maximum-scale=1; minimum-scale=1;" />
```